# Avoid Inserting item in a list on Error code

Tags: android, kotlin, exception, rx-java

So I have a function which is placing a call using RxJava and then this function is supposed to insert the element returned into a list.

So the code works fine. I am able to retrieve and all items in the cart list. However if an error code generated by the getItem appears (getItem place an API call) such 401 or 404..., I want to continue in the iteration and just bypass the insert. I can't use onErrorReturnItem with a null and filter on null after.

```
  return Observable.just(itemResponses)
      .flatMapIterable { it }
      .flatMapSingle { itemResponse ->
        itemWarehouse.getItem(itemResponse.id)
            .map { item ->
              itemData(
                  itemResponse.id,
                  item,
                  itemResponse.info,
                  false,
                  itemResponse.result)
            }
      }
      .map { itemData -> cartMap[itemData.id]?.insert(itemData) }
      .toList()
      .map { cartMap.values.toList() }
}
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
return Observable.just(itemResponses)
      .flatMapIterable { it }
      .flatMap { itemResponse ->
        itemWarehouse.getItem(itemResponse.id)
            .toObservable()
            .map { item ->
              itemData(
                  itemResponse.id,
                  item,
                  itemResponse.info,
                  false,
                  itemResponse.result)
            }
            .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
      }
      .map { itemData -> cartMap[itemData.id]?.insert(itemData) }
      .toList()
      .map { cartMap.values.toList() }
```